# Stacked action bar detection or qualifier

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out if ActionBar is stacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052403/find-out-if-actionbar-is-stacked)

Is there any qualifier or method how to detect, if stacked action bar is used? Or do you know the rules, when the stacked action bar is used (e.g. specific screen size)?

Stacked action bar is described on figures 9 and 10:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a specific method (e.g ActionBar.isStacked()), but you can make a reasonable guess based on some simple rules.  Stacked bars are added on narrow devices (in practice this is typically phones in portrait mode).  The menu items, icon and Title go on the top bar, and tabs go on the stacked bar.  As it mentions in the guide you linked, if you remove the menu items, icon, and title, the top bar will disappear, leaving only the stacked bar.  So if you want only one bar, that would be one workable strategy.

All that said, if you're just trying to use the overlay mode of the ActionBar and need to know how far down to put your content so that the bar doesn't hide it, getHeight() will return the height for the full bar (so both bars if stacked is in effect).

Comment: As an aside, the action bar is more or less meant to take care of itself across different screen sizes and form factors. Your activity content should be determining its size and position based on the information it was passed during measurement and layout, not based on querying other onscreen elements. There are occasional reasons to monitor the size of the action bar but in most cases wanting to query this in the first place is a bit of a code smell.