# Find out if ActionBar is stacked

Tags: android-actionbar, android

If you add tabs to your `ActionBar`, they will be in an extra stacked `ActionBar` on phones in portrait mode. Is there an easy way to find out whether this happened?

I've attached two screenshots of the YouTube app. The first one shows the normal `ActionBar` with the tabs in it, the second one shows the tabs in a stacked `ActionBar`.

[image: Youtube App (landscape)]
[image: Youtube App (portrait)]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to find out if there is one or two lines in action bar by is's height. There is method [`getHeight()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#getHeight%28%29), but it will not work in `onCreate` or `onStart`, it will return real value only if activity already started.

In landscape orientation height of action bar is `40dip` (80/60/40/30 px on different screens), in portrait orientation with tabs it is 96dp (192/144/96/72 px).

It is not the best idea to rely on this, but I can't find any other way to find out if tabs is inside action bar.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is called **Split Action Bar**. It happens when the `AndroidManifest` is set with `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in the `<activity>` or `<application>` element.

Android adjusts the action bar's appearance in a variety of ways, based on the current screen size. Using split action bar is just one option that you can enable to allow the action bar to further optimize the user experience for different screen sizes. In doing so, you may also allow the action bar to collapse navigation tabs into the main action bar. That is, if you use navigation tabs in your action bar, once the action items are separated on a narrow screen, the navigation tabs may be able to fit into the main action bar rather than be separated into the "stacked action bar".

[image: Mock-ups of split action bar with navigation tabs on the left; with the app icon and title disabled on the right.]

You can get more details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar).

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked for. Quoting from the link at the bottom of your post: "When you enable split action bar, *a separate bar appears at the bottom of the screen* to display all action items when the activity is running on a narrow screen (such as a portrait-oriented handset)."

Comment: Stacked ActionBar is different thing from Split ActionBar.  Details are found on the same link referenced in the answer.

Answer (score -2):

well i have created an actionBar similar to Instagram with a bottom ActionBar without the need of using Tabs. have a look at this image . i'v answered this related question on another question 10 minutes ago. 
[image: CustomView ActionBar And Fake Bottom ActionBar]
in order for you to do this you have to create three separate layouts. one for the bottom to use it as `Include` and one for the ActionBar To use it As ActionBar View.

if you check my latest answers you'll find how i did this. 
hope that benefits you in anyway. cheers