# Custom style for stacked action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to have separate backgrounds for stacked and non-stacked tab bars.

This should explain it:

[image]

So the way I have it is:

For tablets, use dark background tabs. For everything else, use light background.

This covers most use cases, but I'd like to make it not look bad in phone-landscape.

Any way I can do this? A style modifier I missed, maybe?

Comment: Shouldn't the styles for phones, landscape be situated in a `values-land` folder?

Comment: It doesn't matter, because landscape doesn't always mean stacked, and vice versa.

Answer (score 9):

You can change the **tab background** depending on stacked/non-stacked ActionBar by setting the light background drawable only for [`android:backgroundStacked`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#backgroundStacked) in your theme.

But then you run into the problem that you can't define the **tab text color** based on stacked/non-stacked layout. That means, the result is either light text on light background or dark text on dark background.

This is already a registered issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26557, so your options now are either waiting or using one of these workarounds:

- Approach based on the available width of the screen: [Android change action bar tab's selector color when split or stacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108637/android-change-action-bar-tabs-selector-color-when-split-or-stacked/13157817#13157817)
- Approach based on the height of your ActionBar: [Find out if ActionBar is stacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052403/find-out-if-actionbar-is-stacked/12853350#12853350)
- Not using `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)` but sticking with old-school [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) or other navigation approaches such as [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) (also supporting tabs)

P.S. I'm also facing this issue as I have a dark ActionBar with light tabs in my app. Still haven't found the perfect solution.

A little off-topic: If you haven't already, use the [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to deal with colors and drawables easier. Again, you'll find no satisfactory configuration for a dark action bar with a light stacked tab bar.