# Android change action bar tab's selector color when split or stacked

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have the action bar set up with tab navigation. On smaller screens the tabs are below the action bar and and bigger screens the tabs are inside the action bar. My actionbar is colored red and the tabs are colored black. When the tabs are below the action bar I would like the selector to be colored red and then change the color to black if the tabs are inside the action bar.

My problem is that I either get a red selector both below and inside the action bar or a black selector both below and inside the action bar. When the tabs are below the actionbar I would like the selector to be red and when they are inside I would like the selector to be black.
Here is my styles_actionbar.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.customabthemegenerated" parent="@android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_customabthemegenerated</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/solid_ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>        
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarText</item>
</style>

<style name="solid_ActionBar" parent="@android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_customabthemegenerated</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_customabthemegenerated</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_customabthemegenerated</item><!-- No difference without it -->
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_inside</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_outside</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I thought the ActionBarTabBarStyle would style the tabs when they are outside the action bar but it seems to have no effect. Are there any way to get a red selector when the action bar is split and a black selector when the action bar is stacked?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this by providing a different style when screen width is above 480dp. Screens smaller than this are considered narrow and action bar is split (and tabs are in the stacked bar).

To do this, create a resource file `res/values-w480dp/style.xml` and define the style of your tabs when they are merged in the action bar. 
In the regular `res/values-w480dp/style.xml`, define the style for your tabs when they are in the stacked action bar.

This will only work for SDK>13.

It's not a very clean solution but it works so far.

Comment: Since JB the tabs are always stacked if the device is in Portrait, even if it's a ten inch tablet, so you'd want to use `res/values-w480dp-land/` instead.

Comment: Can't it be used with SDK <13 somehow?

Comment: Before Android 3.2, it was only possible to define a screen by generalized size groups (large, xlarge...). See: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts